# Radscheduler auto increase or expand appointment height based on the subject

Tags: css, height, appointment, radscheduler

Trying to auto adjust the height of the appointment in radscheduler. I tried this link

http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/details/auto-expand-the-height-of-the-appointment-to-accomodate-the-entire-subject-in-month-view
but to no avail. My appointment length did not increase and moreover the radscheduler shrunk. This has taken so much of my time. I am hoping if someone could help

```
 <telerik:RadScheduler ID="radScheduler" runat="server" SelectedView="MonthView"
                DataKeyField="AppointmentID" DataSubjectField="AppointmentInformation" DataStartField="BeginningDayDate" DataEndField="EndingDayDate" Height="1000px" 
                OnAppointmentUpdate="radScheduler_AppointmentUpdate" OnAppointmentDelete="radScheduler_AppointmentDelete" Font-Bold="true" ShowHeader="true"  
                OnClientAppointmentEditing="OnClientAptEditing" AllowEdit="true" AllowDelete="true" CustomAttributeNames="CompanyLocation,AppointmentInformation"
                EnableCustomAttributeEditing="true" OnAppointmentClick="radScheduler_AppointmentClick" AllowInsert="false" RowHeight="50px" AppointmentStyleMode="Default" OnClientAppointmentMoving="ClientMovingApt"
                DisplayDeleteConfirmation="false" OnNavigationComplete="radScheduler_NavigationComplete" OnAppointmentContextMenuItemClicked="radScheduler_AppointmentContextMenuItemClicked" OnClientAppointmentMoveEnd="OnClientAppointmentMoving"  >
     <MonthView HeaderDateFormat="MMMM yyyy" VisibleAppointmentsPerDay="30" AdaptiveRowHeight="true" >

                </MonthView>

<AppointmentTemplate>
                    <div>
                         <%# HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlDecode(Eval("AppointmentInformation"))%>                             
                    </div>
                </AppointmentTemplate>
            </telerik:RadScheduler>
```

If you need more info, please ask.Thanks

[image: After using the css in that link,the resultant radscheduler]

Answer (score 0):

I sure you would have got answer by this time. For those who are looking for answer,

Set radScheduler.RowHeight=70 where you are calling RadScheduler.ExportToPdf();